# saturated water vapour pressure

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

A pressure steel tube has a volume of 215 cc and contains air at 207 bar. It also contains some water (put it is 0.5 cc) deriving from the condensation of air humidity during pumping air into the pressure tube.

Since this water is a corrosion risk, it is much better if water is eliminated by evaporation. Corrosion may involve explosion risk.

So question is: How much should I lower pressure in the tube steel (from 207 bar) to be sure all water is evaporated?

Is there a formula that can calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends entirely on the composition of the air currently in the tube, and the temperature. I think we can assume that you have saturated the volume of air - which is why you have condensation. How much water is in the air is a sensitive function of temperature - I create a plot below using data from http://intro.chem.okstate.edu/1515sp01/database/vpwater.html:

[image]

At a temperature of 45 C, air can support 0.1 atm of water.

Now you have to evaporate 0.5 ml = 1/36th of a mol of water (molecular weight 18, density 1). This would take up a volume of 22.4 / 36 liters at one atmosphere. To get that much water to evaporate in just 215 cc (about 1/5 th of a liter) you can't simply let out the pressure - you need to heat the container and actively pump air out.

I will leave the details of that calculation to you. But you don't want to leave water corroding a steel vessel at 200+ bar...

Comment: thanks, but temperature change is not an option. I did not mention temperature because it is fixed at ambient temperature, put it is 20 C. But I suspect that there is a solution:if pumping air in the container gives rise to condensation of vapour in atmosfere (because of the increased pressure), then releasing some pressure should restore original condition of having no condensed water. Am I wrong?

Comment: You have added enough water to cover 200 of your containers - you won't get rid of that water unless you give it space to expand to that, or make the air capable of containing 200x more water (by heating). Usually a "condensation trap" is at the bottom of the pressure vessel, so opening a valve at the lowest point will drive the water out without evaporating it.

Comment: yes 200 bar may be 200 times the air filling the container at atmospheric pressure. But pumping the air inside I periodically drain water from the pump, so the water remaining in the container is a small fraction of the original air humidity.  What I would need is a chart as the one you published above, but depending on pressure, not temperature and using constant 20 C temperature. Does a chart like that exist?

Comment: The amount of water that the air in the tank can contain depends only on the _partial_ pressure of air which is a constant for a given temperature. If you drop the pressure to 100 bar you will have take half the evaporated water with you, making space for a bit more moisture. But unless you can drain liquid water from your vessel you won't be able to get rid of that much condensation without pumping out all the air and then some.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. So if you take saturated air and compress it there is less "space" for the water. It is like musical chairs for molecules. Initially there is place for all molecules to be vapor. As you reduce the volume there is no longer enough space so 99.5% of moisture content must condense when you take saturated air down to 1/200th of the volume (from 1 to 200 bar)

Comment: Thanks Floris. I understand you are meaning that the amount of saturated vapour in air only depends on temperature and does NOT depend on pressure. Is it that what you are meaning? If yes, why during pumping from atmosfere to 200 bar so much water gets condensed and drained? Infact, during pumping, most water is drained. What remains in the container is only a minor amount with respect to what is drained.